# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException:Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I try to execute this script:

```
public class BuyMenShirt {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        //Firefox driver setup

        String driverPath = "C:\\Users\\RW\\geckodriver-master\\";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", driverPath + "geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://www.gap.com");

        WebElement menlink = driver.findElement(By.id("division5063"));
        menlink.click();

        WebElement shirtlink = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.sidebar-navigation--category--link[href=/browse/category.do?cid=15043]"));
        shirtlink.click();
    }
}
```

However, I got this error:

```
Nov 01, 2016 2:10:13 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
JavaScript error: http://www.gap.com/, line 20471: TypeError: personalizationService.model.personalizationData.personalizationInfoV1.featureSelections is null
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:43:45 -0700'
System info: host: 'RW-PC', ip: '192.168.0.105', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_112'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities [{rotatable=false, raisesAccessibilityExceptions=false, marionette=true, firefoxOptions={args=[], prefs={}}, appBuildId=20161019084923, version=, platform=XP, proxy={}, command_id=1, specificationLevel=0, acceptSslCerts=false, processId=1692, browserVersion=49.0.2, platformVersion=10.0, XULappId={ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, takesElementScreenshot=true, platformName=windows_nt, device=desktop}]
Session ID: 9c166d1b-3391-4ed9-8fac-3afe6d09b13f
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:622)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:368)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByCssSelector(RemoteWebDriver.java:465)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByCssSelector.findElement(By.java:430)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:360)
    at BuyMenShirt.main(BuyMenShirt.java:27)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expected one element but was: <org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodes$KnownError@cd2dae5, org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodes$KnownError@4973813a>
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators.getOnlyElement(Iterators.java:322)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterables.getOnlyElement(Iterables.java:284)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodes.toStatus(ErrorCodes.java:138)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:92)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:42)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:163)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    ... 5 more
```

Did I do something wrong? I notice I got some JavaScript error right before `UnreachableBrowserException`. Does it matter?

Comment: Why geckodriver? What happens if you delete the first two lines referring to geckodriver?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue